# Error using arules - Error in asMethod(object)

Tags: r, arules

```
library(arules)
library(rattle)

data <- read.csv('R/347_347.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
Data <- data[c(3:23)]
#error in here
trans <- as(Data, "transactions")
```

> ```
> Error in asMethod(object) : 
>   column(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the How to Ask section and take a few moments to learn about our formatting tools. It will be helpful in the future. For now, I have tried to fix your question. Also please remember to use *reproducible* examples; not ones dependent on files on your computer.

Comment: It would be interesting to see, what is in your csv-data. But it seems that the type of a column is not correct and you have to convert it frst.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the data types of your columns.

You need to first convert them to discrete column types like `factor` (please see https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html ). Another option is `logical`, i.e. the boolean values of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

For example:

```
my_data_frame$x <- as.factor(my_data_frame$x)
```

You need to do this for each categorical column, such as those mentioned by index number in the error message.

For example:

```
data(iris)

iris[,1] <- as.factor(iris[,1])
iris[,2] <- as.factor(iris[,2])
iris[,3] <- as.factor(iris[,3])
iris[,4] <- as.factor(iris[,4])
iris[,5] <- as.factor(iris[,5])

iris = as(iris, "transactions")

iris
```

> ```
> transactions in sparse format with
>  150 transactions (rows) and
>  126 items (columns)
> ```

***Or, even more compactly:***

```
data(iris)
iris = as(data.frame(lapply(iris, as.character), stringsAsFactors=T), "transactions")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example which uses some data from the arules package:

```
library(arules);
data("AdultUCI");
str(AdultUCI)
Adult = as(AdultUCI, "transactions");

AdultUCI <- dplyr::select(AdultUCI, "workclass", "marital-status", "occupation")
str(AdultUCI)

Adult = as(AdultUCI, "transactions");
```

First, you will see that with the first try to convert it to transactions, the method will fail, giving the same error as yours.
But if you select only the factors ("workclass", "marital-status", "occupation"), the method works.

Comment: This is true, but he may not want to throw away what appears to be every column of his data.